# Booting win10 from new cloned ssd

Tags: ssd, installation

Sorry I have found other questions very similar but am still having problems and was hoping for some help. 
Have Asus laptop, 1tb HDD with windows 10. 
Installed new Samsung nvme ssd 500gb. Got original install down to 200gb on 1tb and formated ssd, used Samsung migration to clone HDD to SSD.  When I reset and go to bios I can chose either SSD or HDD as primary boot, but when I start windows it is still using the old HDD install. I had to load Partition manager in windows and bring SSD online because there was an Id conflict. Now it assigned a unique Id to SSD and I have 2 identical drives as c: and d: when I look.  If I physically remove the HDD the system won't boot I get the windows recovery thing but nothing really works.  Do I somehow have to repair/install the MBR on the SSD? 
I would just do a fresh install but there is some specific software I am using that I cannot easily reinstall. Hope this makes sense I feel like I am close to having it working thank you.

Comment: -- what if i make a usb recovery disk using the the windows tool, then unplug the hdd, and use the stick to repair windows on the new ssd?

Comment: Issue is that you cannot have duplicate UUID or with gpt duplicate GUIDs. UEFI uses GUID to know which ESP to boot from. If duplicates, it may select whichever one it sees first on each boot which may then have updates on one system one time and other next time.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard--got it going.
My mistake was trying to reboot with the clone and source still installed. Created a conflict and when I mounted the ssd with partition manager it gave it a unique id that bios didnt recognize the first time i tried to boot with the ssd alone (i think)

Formatted ssd and did the samsung migration again and immediately removed the hdd then rebooted- windows was loaded before i could push f2 to check ssd was set to boot!

Now Ill just hook up the original hdd with a usb connector i have, format it then   reidentify it with diskpart to be sure and i should be good to put it back in.